# Event ID 1645 Replication Changes

Tags: active-directory

I am having problems with Active Directory Domain Services. I have a lot of errors, id 1645:

> Active Directory Domain Services did not perform an authenticated remote procedure call (RPC) to another directory server because the desired service principal name (SPN) for the destination directory server is not registered on the Key Distribution Center (KDC) domain controller that resolves the SPN.
>
> Destination directory server:
> e73e1bb7-a691-40d0-9978-0a9b73a06d78._msdcs.ucacsa.org
> SPN: E3514235-4B06-11D1-AB04-00C04FC2DCD2/e73e1bb7-a691-40d0-9978-0a9b73a06d78/ucacsa.org@ucacsa.org
>
> User Action
> Verify that the names of the destination directory server and domain are correct. Also, verify that the SPN is registered on the KDC domain controller. If the destination directory server has been recently promoted, it will be necessary for the local directory server’s account data to replicate to the KDC before this directory server can be authenticated.

The results of setspn is the following and I don't know how to resolve the error:

```
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=DCNCG,OU=Domain
Controllers,DC=ucacsa,DC=org:
TERMSRV/DCNCG
TERMSRV/DCNCG.ucacsa.org
DNS/DCNCG.ucacsa.org
HOST/DCNCG/UCACSA
HOST/DCNCG.ucacsa.org/UCACSA
GC/DCNCG.ucacsa.org/ucacsa.org
HOST/DCNCG.ucacsa.org/ucacsa.org
ldap/DCNCG/UCACSA
ldap/84e148a7-24e5-4d62-b054-5eaa8753e343._msdcs.ucacsa.org
ldap/DCNCG.ucacsa.org/UCACSA
ldap/DCNCG
ldap/DCNCG.ucacsa.org
ldap/DCNCG.ucacsa.org/ForestDnsZones.ucacsa.org
ldap/DCNCG.ucacsa.org/DomainDnsZones.ucacsa.org
ldap/DCNCG.ucacsa.org/ucacsa.org
Dfsr-12F9A27C-BF97-4787-9364-D31B6C55EB04/DCNCG.ucacsa.org
WSMAN/DCNCG.ucacsa.org
WSMAN/DCNCG
E3514235-4B06-11D1-AB04-00C04FC2DCD2/84e148a7-24e5-4d62-b054-5eaa8753e343/ucacsa.org
NtFrs-88f5d2bd-b646-11d2-a6d3-00c04fc9b232/DCNCG.ucacsa.org
RestrictedKrbHost/DCNCG
HOST/DCNCG
RestrictedKrbHost/DCNCG.ucacsa.org
HOST/DCNCG.ucacsa.org
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you in fact have more than one Domain Controller?

Comment: Indeed, I have another 2 Domain Controllers... this one is located in a branch.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What your DC is looking for was E3514235-4B06-11D1-AB04-00C04FC2DCD2/e73e1bb7-a691-40d0-9978-0a9b73a06d78/ucacsa.org@ucacsa.org, which is not listed in your spn dump.

did you try below?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308111

Comment: I added the SPN, but I don't know why it just disappeared!

Comment: You should always copy and paste relevant solutions from sources into your answer so that if links should fail, users can still find the solutions they're looking for.